# how to add numbers at even position in fibonacci series in R?

Tags: r

The fibonacci series is obtained by adding together the prior two integers in the series, the Series include 1, 1, 2 , 3, 5 , 8. I used the following code to have series till 50.

```
y <- 50
}
fibvals <- numeric(y)
fibvals[1] <- 1
fibvals[2] <- 1
for (i in 3:y) { 
fibvals[i] <- fibvals[i-1]+fibvals[i-2]
}
```

Now i want to add the numbers at even position, i.e 1, 3, 8 till 50th number? please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `seq` to select the even vector indices from 2 to 50, like this:

```
sum(fibvals[seq(2, 50, by = 2)])
```

Also: there are R libraries to make working with series easier. You could use the `numbers` package for example, to get the first 50 Fibonacci numbers:

```
fibvals <- sapply(1:50, numbers::fibonacci)
```